# C++ - List files in a directory using file descriptor

Tags: c++, linux

When I have a file descriptor pointing to a directory, is that possible to get a list of files in that directory in C++?

If I try to use default functions for reading, it, of course, throws an error.

I'm trying to reproduce that on Ubuntu

Comment: When you say that you have a file descriptor to a directory, I assume you're on a POSIX or POSIX-like system, like Linux or macOS? Is that correct? Then please [edit] your question to include that information (and add relevant tags). Also please tell us what you current have, and what you have tried, in the form of a [mre]. Give us all the details for the problems you currently have. Also please tell us the actual and underlying problem that the program is supposed to solve.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If you are using C++17 or later, you should also take a look at [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an open file descriptor for a directory, you can use [`fdopendir()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man3/fdopendir.3.html) to get a `DIR` pointer that can be used with [`readdir()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man3/readdir.3.html) to iterate through its contents.